# Gnome Terminal Adjust Tab Height

Tags: command-line, 16.04, gnome, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

I'm running Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 on a laptop with low resolution (1366x768). I've been able to adjust most things in Gnome to look much better on this display, but the gnome-terminal tabs seem to elude me. I'd like to be able to make the pixel height a bit smaller to it does not look as ugly (I bet it looks awesome in a high-dpi display)...

I guess something could be added to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css like I had to do for the title bar - but I don't know squat about css, and my google-fu does not seem to be yielding any good results.

Comment: Ah Ha - My google-fu is strong, found the answer here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869701/decrease-the-tabs-bar-height-in-gnome-terminal/37117041#37117041?newreg=f80524a906424ad38cce6367f450d4a9) but be sure to logout/login after making the changes. ALT+F2 and typing restart did not do the trick for me.

Answer (score 4):

Found an edit to ~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36869701/decrease-the-tabs-bar-height-in-gnome-terminal/37117041#37117041?newreg=f80524a906424ad38cce6367f450d4a9) by @Lari Hotari over at stackoverflow.

It doesn't remove the buttons, but makes them nicer for a dark theme and use less vertical space.

```
TerminalWindow .notebook .button,
TerminalWindow .notebook .button:active {
   padding: 2 2 2 10;
   background-image: none;
   border: 0;
}
```

I'm using this customization, works well with a dark theme (also found in the above link):

```
@define-color bg-grey #222;
@define-color active-grey #333;
@define-color border-grey #555;

TerminalWindow .notebook {
   border: 0;
   padding: 0;
   color: #eee;
   background-color: shade(@active-grey, 1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab:active {
   border: 1px solid @border-grey;
   background-color: shade(@active-grey, 1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook tab {
   background-color: shade(@bg-grey, 1);
}

TerminalWindow .notebook .button,
TerminalWindow .notebook .button:active {
   padding: 2 2 2 10;
   background-image: none;
   border: 0;
}
```

Then logout of your session and log back in, the theme should take effect. ALT+F2 and typing "restart" did not work for me, but your mileage may vary.